# Unable to Autowire

Tags: java, spring-boot

Using Spring Initializer to create a simple Spring boot. I am only choosing DevTools under the options available.

After creating the project, without making any changes  to it, able to run the program fine.

Now when I try to do some Autowiring in the project, it simply doesn't work. I don't get it. Been looking all over previous questions here which has resolutions for it but none works plus there is nothing complex about what I am doing in my case as follows. Please advice what I am missing.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    //  @Autowired
    //  private static Maker maker; // Stopped using this cos I wanted to check if the autowiring is not working in this class only or anywhere. Turns out it is anywhere. 

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
            Maker maker = new Maker();
            maker.printName(); // Fails cos of ServiceHelper Autowiring 
        }
    }


@Service
public class Maker {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceHelper serviceHelper;

    public void printName(){
        System.out.println("This is from the method body itself.");
        System.out.println("Auto wiring works cos I got this -> " + serviceHelper.help());
    }
}

@Component
public class ServiceHelper {
    public String help(){
        return "...FROM HELPER...";
    }
}
```

StackTrace

> Exception in thread "restartedMain"
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.example.demo.services.Maker.printName(Maker.java:15)  at
>   com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:17)    ... 5
>   more

Comment: You cannot autowire static fields.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I have commented out static field.

Comment: @kang check my answer for a work around on injecting dependencies in a static field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create any bean using `new` keyword that bean will not added to `Spring Application Context`, and this is one way to `@Autowire` static beans

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    private static Maker maker; 

    @Autowired
    private Maker tMaker;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
    DemoApplication.maker = tMaker;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        maker.printName();  
    }
}
```

or you can do `Autowire` using `Constructor` the instance of `Maker` is injected as an argument to the constructor when `DemoApplication` is created

```
@Autowired
public DemoApplication(Maker maker) {
    DemoApplication.maker = maker;
    }
```

or you can use `@Autowired` on setter method, the setter method is called with the instance of `Maker` when `DemoApplication` is created

```
@Autowired
public void setMaker(Maker maker) {
        DemoApplication.maker = maker
}
```

Comment: This certainly works. Though I thought static Auto wiring is not possible based on above comment yet this seems to prove it is possible.

Comment: There are still more ways also @kang

Comment: The autowired on the static field is pointless. What is happening here is you are autowiring the second Maker, the instance field, and setting it after the bean as been init'd.

Comment: updated another approach, i'm just providing approaches for static beans @DarrenForsythe

Answer (score 1):

You create yourself an instance, its `ServiceHelper` does not get autowired by Spring:

```
Maker maker = new Maker();
```

You can access bean via `ApplicationContext`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext cts = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        Maker maker = ctx.getBean(Maker.class);
        maker.printName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the solution here to get the auto wire working?

Comment: It means, `ServiceHelper` will not be auto-wired in `Maker` because `Maker` is not added to Spring application context. Maker is created using `new` keyword. Spring has no knowledge of it.

Comment: @Hima I get that. I am asking how to resolve this if I want to call Maker in the main method? Unable to Autowire static, unable to use 'new', whats the solution here?

Comment: you can check my answer there are couple of ways to `@Autowire` static beans @kang

Answer (score 0):

When you use `new Maker()` you are not using the bean Spring created for you and as a result the the object you have is uninitialized as dependencies are not injected.

You need to get the bean which the Spring framework created, like I did below as directly you cannot autowire static fields:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    private static Maker maker;

    @Autowired
    public void setMaker(Maker maker) {
        DemoApplication.maker = maker;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        maker.printName();
    }
}
```